Problem in accessing running deloyed container on EC2
I created simple nodeJS application with docker and when I run it locally, everything works fine. I've installed Docker and Docker-Compose on my EC2 instance then deployed docker container on it but web-app is not accessible even through:

Instance Public IPv4 address: 13.48.193.158   or
Public IPv4 DNS: ec2-13-48-193-158.eu-north-1.compute.amazonaws.com

Test Project files:
https://github.com/mostafanabil71/Simple-test-NodeJSApp-with-docker.git
EC2 Instance inbound rules:

Container on Instance logs

Dockerfile:
FROM node:10-alpine
RUN mkdir -p /home/node/app/node_modules && chown -R node:node /home/node/app
WORKDIR /home/node/app
COPY package*.json ./
USER node
RUN npm install
COPY --chown=node:node . .
EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "node", "app.js" ]


a. Docker version 26.1.4, build 5650f9b
b. npm version 10.8.1
c. node version v12.22.9
d. Docker Compose version v2.27.1-desktop.1
e. npm express: 10.8.1
f. installed platform on EC2 is ubuntu-noble-24.04-amd64-server-20240423

problem was solved after lunching the Security groups and editing the inbound rules  as below image and easily APP was accessible by entering IP:Port in the web URL


In your Dockerfile, you exposed only port 8080,  you didn't expose the port 80. if you want to run your application on port 8080, add it as well on your security group.   Furthermore, I will recommend you run your nodejs server behind nginx
Also upon, checking your application source code, you have to replace these lines with the correct port.
const path = __dirname + '/views/';
const port = 8080;

change it to port = 80
Once again, use nginx is much better

thank you for your help but actually it was the about security groups inbound rules i used nginx with the same result so after checking it was about inbound rules and both of app or nginx worked fine.

@MostafaNabil you're both right. Ultimately the ports you exposed in the container did not match the security rules. You could have fixed either. I'd say that for a public site it's better to just expose port 443 and set up SSL but if going over port 8080 works for you then good for you.

@Evert yes you are right ..to be more clarified I'm new to docker tech so I was testing my knowledge to perform this app and deploying it to the aws ec2 on port 80 as a first step in order to take the next step and trying to expose on port 443 using SSL which is of course is better.
